# WPF window appearance is not same with design view

Tags: c#, wpf, cornerradius, borderless

I create WPF application. I want to create borderless window. For that my code as follow

```
<Window x:Class="AzLeks.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Height="600.586" Width="826.694" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="False"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<!--<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/bckgr.png" />
</Window.Background>-->
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Close" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="-9,-13,-9,-16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="630" Width="845">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="235*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border CornerRadius="12" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" >
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/bckgr.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
     <!--Some Content-->
    </Grid>
```

In design mode it shown as follow:
[image]

But after runing the app it shown as:
[image]
I don't know what is a problem here. PLease help me, I can't find solution for this

Comment: without the xaml code it's quite impossible to figure out what is going on here. Also please make sure that there is nothing going on in code-behind/C# code that manipulates the window.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, I edit my question. I have not any c# code that manipulates the window.

Comment: Your Window is smaller than your Grid. You even make it worse with the Margin. One thing is for sure, the sizes you see in the design are almost never the same as runtime. I would say add a border before the grid. Don't give it any margin and make your Windows totally transparent. You can add your background to the border instead

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, But I want cornerRadius for window. How can I do this with your sugestion?

Comment: @ElvinMammadov Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
<Window x:Class="AzLeks.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Height="600" Width="820" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown=" MainWindow_OnMouseLeftButtonDown" Loaded="Window_Loaded"     WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="Close" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Border CornerRadius="12" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" >
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/bckgr.png"></ImageBrush>
    </Border.Background>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" >

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="235*" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <!--Some Content-->
</Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: I tried such method befour your. Result is same. Rounding is working but there is another problem, please look at: http://screencast.com/t/jPc7CpDAS0

Comment: @ElvinMammadov that problem is solved in my solution. Allowtransparency = true and background Transparent

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help